# New missing/unsatisfied dependencies Error in WildFly 9

Tags: java, configuration, ejb, wildfly

I am migrating from Jboss7 to WildFly 9.

When starting WildFly 9 I am getting the following error. I am starting the server from eclipse with an application deployed.

This same application had no issue starting in Jboss7

```
 WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
       service jboss.remoting.endpoint.subsystem.outbound-connection.remote-ejb-connection (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.dd-based-ejb-client-context."test.war".internal-remoting-profile] 



 10:18:43,087 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 30273ms - Started 338 of 513 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 220 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)


 WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
       service jboss.ejb3.dd-based-ejb-client-context."test.war" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".ejb3.client-context.registration-service, service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL] 
       service jboss.ejb3.dd-based-ejb-client-context."test.war".internal-remoting-profile (missing) dependents: [service jboss.ejb3.dd-based-ejb-client-context."test.war"] 
       service jboss.naming.context.java.app.test(missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL] 
       service jboss.naming.context.java.module.test.test(missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".INSTALL]
```

I have checked some similar questions on here but none of them seems to have answer. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Have i missed some configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had missed the outbound connection tag in the standalone.xml, Once i added the tag with the necessary data the error went off.

Comment: I get the same caution. What is "Outbound connection tag"?

Comment: In the <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0"> tag we need to add the tag <outbound-connections> refer the link for the configuration [jboss ejb config](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-call-ejbs-from-another-jboss-as-7-instance)